# Using custom gradient

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-xml

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/29/download-file-android-device-remote-server-custom-progressbar-showing-progress/  is the code im using the second from last box where it has

```
<gradient
                android:startColor="@color/greenStart"
                android:centerColor="@color/greenMid"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/greenEnd"
                android:angle="270"
        />
```

is where im having my problems it shows an error in my eclipse [image]
right here is my problem how do i fix this?? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you did not define the color resources.
I usually create a file called colors.xml in my values folder where i specify all color values i need and use. For example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="greenStart">#7cfc00</color>
    </resources>
```

You specify the color value using a # symbol followed by the (optional) alpha channel, and then the red, green, and blue values using one or two hexadecimal numbers. #RGB, #RRGGBB, #ARGB and #AARRGGBB all work.

Answer (score 3):

probably you forget to define color resources in `res/values/color.xml`. define it as:

```
<resources>
<color name="greenStart">#ff33dd44</color>
<color name="greenMid">#ff0A8815</color>
<color name="greenEnd">#ff1da130</color>
</resources>
```

and also clear and build project after making changes in color.xml